# Is it possible to Use MotionLayout or Transition for Shared Element?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-motionlayout

I have a full-screen [**Fragment A**] Here. And what I need is that, when this full-screen Fragment closed, it comes a new full-screen [**Fragment B**],which is a container of a viewPager. I need An animation from Fragment A to one item in ViewPager index=1 fragment in  Fragment B.

In Fragment B, there is a ViewPager with 4 separated Fragments,(actually it's the main page of APP, and Fragment 1 is the Welcome Page). I want welcome Fragment Scale into one item in mainFragment (MainFragment has a viewpager, index=1 is Home).

Thank you for helping me out! I have searched for a lone while...

Answer (score 0):

In general MotionLayout is not designed to support Fragment to Fragment transitions.

You may be able to "fake" it by creating a MotionLayout with the layouts for the start and end Fragment and post switch to end animate from the start to end constraintSet. But in general this is difficult to get correct.